# @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.2.2): Connection WebChannel transport errored (HOW TO FIX THIS?) I cant find any solutions its been 1 week already

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[my Code for firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSeoT.png)

[my Code for firestore SET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3flE3.png)

I have tried:

1. firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true,merge:true });
2. firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true });
3. firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling:true});

Nothing works ... still getting the error.

This is the ERROR:

**WARN  [2022-07-07T23:56:51.946Z]**  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.2.2): Connection WebChannel transport errored: {"a": {"C": null, "K": [Circular], "a":
{"A": 0, "B": [U], "C": true, "F": 45000, "G": false, "I": true, "J": -1, "K": "qWV1iUI-i7uAv4TY0w-d_A", "Ka": 5000, "Ma": false, "Na": false, "Oa": false,
"P": 0, "Pa": 2, "Qa": undefined, "R": [Object], "S": 0, "T": 65073, "Ta": 1, "U": true, "Ua": 10000, "V": 4, "X": false, "Y": [Object], "a": null, "b": [zd], "c": [bc], "f": [Z], "fa": false, "g": [Array], "ga": undefined, "h": null, "ha": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "i": null, "ia": "", "j": null, "ja": 8, "l": null, "m": null, "ma": 12, "na": [U], "o": 3, "oa": 600000, "pa": "Gw6V9oY7XHlRiEFuqqRCs5zpnZf9pAwBw2sVbO1PSVM", "qa": -1, "ra": [Ed], "s": null, "u": 0, "v": "gsessionid"}, "b": {"database": "projects/banana-ee2ef/databases/(default)"}, "c": {"a": [Object], "b": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "f": {"a": [Circular]}, "i": undefined, "j": false, "l": true, "m": true, "o": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel"}, "defaultPrevented": false, "status": 1, "target": {"C": null, "K": [Circular], "a": {"A": 0, "B": [U], "C": true, "F": 45000, "G": false, "I": true, "J": -1, "K": "qWV1iUI-i7uAv4TY0w-d_A", "Ka": 5000, "Ma": false, "Na": false, "Oa": false, "P": 0, "Pa": 2, "Qa": undefined, "R": [Object], "S": 0, "T": 65073, "Ta": 1, "U": true, "Ua": 10000, "V": 4, "X": false, "Y": [Object], "a": null, "b": [zd], "c": [bc], "f": [Z], "fa": false, "g": [Array], "ga": undefined, "h": null, "ha": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "i": null, "ia": "", "j": null, "ja": 8, "l": null, "m": null, "ma": 12, "na": [U], "o": 3, "oa": 600000, "pa": "Gw6V9oY7XHlRiEFuqqRCs5zpnZf9pAwBw2sVbO1PSVM", "qa": -1, "ra": [Ed], "s": null, "u": 0, "v": "gsessionid"}, "b": {"database": "projects/banana-ee2ef/databases/(default)"}, "c": {"a": [Object], "b": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "f": {"a": [Circular]}, "i": undefined, "j": false, "l": true, "m": true, "o": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel"}, "type": "c"}

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar error discussed [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6181) but it's related configuration of the local emulator. Are you using the emulator?

Are you only having problems with the '[set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document)' method with this particular collection and/or document?

Note, that the `Firestore` reference should be the db reference obtained from the below method.

`const db = firebase.firestore();`.

It's not really clear how you are setting up the database. Could you share that code here too?

And just a minor comment. You can simplify your code like below:

```
{
  userId,
  email,
  password,
  username,
}
```

See https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-object-property-shorthand

Comment: I have edited the post .. see the picture... actually i did it like this: const db = firebase.firestore(); .. like ur example..

Comment: I am not using emulator thou

Comment: There are many of these posts on SO and no good answer yet from what I've seen. My own similar post with example code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73709757/firebase-firestore-9-9-4-webchannel-transport-errored-and-empty-data-returne

Answer (score 0):

You can try switching to fire base version 8.10.1

```
 yarn add firebase@8.10.1
```

or

```
 npm install --save firebase@8.10.1
```